# Does Python's multiprocessing.Pool support remote subprocesses?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have recently discovered how awesome `Pool.map()` is for simple multiprocessing tasks, but my local machine only has two processors and I was hoping to take advantage of some remote computing resources.

Can a processing pool be constructed to use remote machines as well as the local machines in a transparent way?

What python code would I need to run on the remote machines, How would I set up the pool on the local (master) machine?

On [the documentation page for multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), It says Managers are to be used for shared objects, but it's unclear to me how they should be used for a remote Pool. Nothing other than Managers seems make any reference to ports and addresses, so I'm guessing all remote activity happens through this class.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181949/using-the-multiprocessing-module-for-cluster-computing

Comment: Thanks's that was very helpful. I think jug (a link from that page) is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

`multiprocessing.Pool` seems not designed for distributed processing -- if that's what you want to do, I suggest you check out the [`execnet`](http://codespeak.net/execnet/) package instead. That works over SSH pipes and sends code along to the remote Python interpreter if necessary.