# How to structure code that distributes jobs to threads/nodes in Python?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, distutils, setup.py

I have python code that takes a bunch of tasks and distributes them to either different threads or different nodes on a cluster. I always end up writing a main script `driver.py`, that takes two command line arguments: `--run-all` and `--run-task`. The first is just a wrapper that iterates through all tasks and then calls `driver.py --run-task` with each task passed as argument.  Example:

```
== driver.py ==
# Determine the current script
DRIVER = os.path.abspath(__file__)
(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
if opts.run_all is not None:
  # Run all tasks
   for task in opts.run_all.split(","):
     # Call driver.py again with a specific task
     cmd = "python %s --run-task %s" %(DRIVER, task)
     # Execute on system
     distribute_cmd(cmd)
elif opts.run_task is not None:
  # Run on an individual task
  # code here for processing a task...
```

The user would then call:

```
$ driver.py --run-all task1,task2,task3,task4
```

And each task would get distributed.

The function `distribute_cmd` takes a shell executable command and sends in a system-specific way to either a node or a thread. The reason `driver.py` has to find its own name and call itself is because `distribute_cmd` needs an executable shell command; it cannot take a function name for example.

This consideration led me to this design, of a driver script having two modes and having to call itself. This has two complications: (1) the script has to find out its own path via `__file__` and (2) when making this into a Python package, it's unclear where `driver.py` should go. It's meant to be an executable scripts, but if I put it in `setup.py`'s `scripts=`, then I will have to find out where the scripts live (see [correct way to find scripts directory from setup.py in Python distutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975540/correct-way-to-find-scripts-directory-from-setup-py-in-python-distutils)). This does not seem to be a good solution.

What's an alternative design to this?  Keep in mind that the distribution of tasks has to result in an executable command that can be passed as a string to `distribute_cmd`.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- are you looking for is a library that already does exactly what you need, e.g. [`Fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org) or [`Celery`](http://celeryproject.org/).
- if you were not using nodes, I would suggest using `multiprocessing`.
- this is a slightly similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618609/does-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-support-remote-subprocesses)

**To be able to execute remotely**, you either need:

- `ssh` access to the box, in that case you can use `Fabric` to send your commands.
- a server, `SocketServer`, tcp server, or anything that will accept connections.
- an agent, or client, that will wait for data, if you are using a agent, you may as well use a **broker** for your messages. `Celery` allows you to do some of the plumbing, one end `puts` messages on the **queue** while the other end `gets` message from the queue. If the message is a command to execute, then the agent can do an `os.system()` call, or call `subprocess.Popen()`

**celery example:**

```
 import os
 from celery import Celery
 celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
 @celery.task
 def run_command(command):
    return os.system(command)
```

You will then need a worker that binds on the queue and waits for tasks to execute. [More info in the documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).

**fabric example:**

the code:

```
from fabric.api import run
def exec_remotely(command):
   run(command)
```

the invocation:

```
$ fab exec_remotely:command='ls -lh'
```

[More info in the documentation](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#task-arguments).

**batch system case:**
To go back to the question...

- `distribute_cmd` is something that would call `bsub somescript.sh`
- you need to find **file** only because you are going to re-execute the same script with other parameters
- because of the above, you might have a problem providing a correct `distutils` script.

Let's question this design.

- Why do you need to use the same script?
- Can your driver write scripts then call bsub?
- Can you use temporary files?
- Do all the nodes actually share a filesystem?
- How do you know **file** is going to exist on the node?

example:

```
TASK_CODE = {
   'TASK1': '''#!/usr/bin/env python
#... actual code for task1 goes here ...
''',
   'TASK2': '''#!/usr/bin/env python
#... actual code for task2 goes here ...
'''}
# driver portion
(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
if opts.run_all is not None:
   for task in opts.run_all.split(","):
      task_path = '/tmp/taskfile_%s' % task
      with open(task_path, 'w') as task_file:
         task_file.write(TASK_CODE[task])
      # note: should probably do better error handling.
      distribute_cmd(task_path)
```

Comment: I don't want to rely on a complex framework and I don't see yet how it would solve this problem - could you explain? The lowest level of execution is something like "qsub myscript.sh" - so anything I do from Python has to be a shell executable command in the end.... the question is how to allow that without knowing the script name since Python does not really support that

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide more details on how the code gets distributed. do you use ssh? do you use client - server?

Comment: The code just gets distributed by automatically making a shell script (an executable `.sh` file) and then passing that to the cluster submission system, in this case `bsub thescript.sh`. I don't know if any cluster can support `celery` or related packages in this way

Comment: To answer your excellent questions about the design: it does not need to be the same script. `driver` might as well call something else - but I don't see how this changes anything, it just pushes the problem to the other script. I can use temporary files, they are all on the head node. The shell script is in fact an intermediate temporary file, containing the call to my Python script. Executing `qsub thatscript.sh` does all the submission to the nodes  so that I don't ever have to deal with the nodes. They do happen to share a file system but I never need to explicitly work on nodes

Comment: I meant for the temporary file to have the actual code to be executed rather than a call to your script. If you can rely on the filesystem to be shared, then getting to correct path from __file__ is just fine. This assumption will simplify your problem, but your problem seems more of a batch job scheduling problem than a distributed computing. My answer is more generic than having to work with `qsub`.